# Text rendered using FTGL not visible

Tags: c++, opengl, ftgl

I'm building a rendering engine using OpenGL and I'd like to add a minecraft-like debug overlay.

For those of you that don't know what I'm talking about:

[image: Minecraft debug overlay]

I'm using FTGL to do the font rendering, and I'm using this code (I'm also rendering a few other things (using GL_TRIANGLE as a primitive) and they all do what they are supposed to do

Initial setup:

```
FTGLPixmapFont debugFont (debugFontStr.c_str());

if (debugFont.Error())
{
    std::cerr << "[GameScreen::renderLoop()]\tFailed to load debugging font" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    if(!debugFont.FaceSize(static_cast<unsigned int> (debugFontSize)))
    {
        std::cerr << "[GameScreen::renderLoop()]\tCouldn't set fontSize" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Main renderloop (The relevant part atleast):

```
glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glColor4d(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
debugFont.Render(this->generateDebugOutput().c_str());

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glPopAttrib();

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(this->sdlWindow);
```

Unfortunately, the FTGL text is not visible on my screen.
I am using multiple texture units througout my program, if that's a relevant factor.

I've checked the result of `this->generateDebugOutput()` and it generates a normal C++ string.
I'm not using `GL_LIGHTING`, I've checked the effect of disabling it before I render and re-enabling it when I'm done, no effect.

Could any of you maybe give me some pointers about what might be causing this behaviour?

I'm using SDL2 to create my window, this is my initialization code for SDL, OpenGL and GLEW:

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) >= 0)
{
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, GameScreen::OPENGL_MAJOR_VERSION);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, GameScreen::OPENGL_MINOR_VERSION);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

    SDL_DisplayMode dm;
    SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(0, &dm);
    this->screenWidth = dm.w;
    this->screenHeight = dm.h;
    this->frameCap = dm.refresh_rate;

    this->sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(GameScreen::DEFAULT_TITLE.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, this->screenWidth, this->screenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (this->sdlWindow != NULL)
    {
        this->openGLContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(this->sdlWindow);
        if (this->openGLContext != NULL)
        {
            glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
            GLenum glewError = glewInit();
            if (glewError == GLEW_OK)
            {
                if (SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1) < 0)
                {
                    std::cout << "[GameScreen::GameScreen()]\tWARNING: Unable to use VSync: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr << "[GameScreen::GameScreen()]\tFailed to intialize GLEW: " << glewGetErrorString(glewError) << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "[GameScreen::GameScreen()]\tFailed to create OpenGL Context from SDL2 Window: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "[GameScreen::GameScreen()]\tFailed to create SDL2 Window: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "[GameScreen::GameScreen()]\tFailed to intialize SDL2: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To everyone that's interested, I was unfortunately unable to solve this, but the nice folks over at [/r/opengl](https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl) were able to recommend me some other libraries:

- stb_truetype - https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_truetype.h
- glText - https://github.com/vallentin/glText

The reddit thread can be found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/6taul5/text_rendered_using_ftgl_not_visible/